# Docker : Change open Jdk to oracle Jdk in Jenkins image

Tags: jenkins, docker, jenkins-plugins

I am very new to docker and I am trying to run a Jenkins image. I pulled the image from the repository and now am able to run it using the command

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 jenkinsci/jenkins
```

By default it uses openjdk version 1.8. I would like to use oracle Jdk instead of openjdk. How could I change this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to use this image and change the jdk, you will have to build your own image from this one, install oraclejdk, setup Jenkins to use this jdk (like environment variables etc), but it is not a clean way, imho.

The best practice would be to build your own image from a oraclejdk Docker image and setup Jenkins on it.

You should look at other Dockerfiles to do this.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Will look into the docker images.

Comment: I may be not clear. If you want more information, just ask :)

Comment: Yeah. What I am thinking is to have a oraclejdk8 image along with jenkins image, merge them so that I can get both in one image. Hope this is correct

Comment: I think the best way then, is to use a oraclejdk8 Docker base image and then build your own image (Dockerfile) with jenkins install and eventually publish it to Docker hub. It may be useful for others ;)

Comment: Yeah that is what I've planned. :)

Comment: Cool ! Tell me if you did it. Don't hesitate to accept answer too

Comment: Yes did that. Installed jenkins and oracle jdk 8 and created an image.

Comment: Happy for you :) Accept my answer if it helped

Answer (score 1):

Oracle provides a bunch of docker images on github : https://github.com/oracle/docker-images

You should check your other requirements as well (OS, etc.)

Comment: You can find some custom examples (https://hub.docker.com/r/stephenreed/jenkins-java8-maven-git/~/dockerfile/) to base yourself on, but in the end the use of Open-JDK in the official images is simply a license issue for Debian (as explained of the docker hub https://hub.docker.com/_/java/).

Comment: built a small centos container, added jenkins and jdk8 and commited the image. This way i was able to do it.

Comment: Great. Any link to this image on docker hub ?

Comment: no have not put in docker hub. Had install other plugins, company related security features and hosted in a private registry.